# how to return only specific select query from stored procedure in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i'm using sql server stored procedure and EF6 - c# for my server code.
i have several select query in my SP and i want to access the last one in c# code.
but it returned only first query to c#.
also i cant bring all SELECTs together for UNION or etc.
(sorry about bad grammar. i'm not native)
here is my code:

stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ACars_Insert] 
(
@MainCategoryCode AS NVARCHAR(2) = NULL,
@SubCategoryName AS NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ActionResultTag AS INT = 0
DECLARE @GeneralNameCode AS NVARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @SubCategoryCode AS NVARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @GeneralNameTitle AS NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @GoodCode AS NVARCHAR(14)

IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tb_Goods WHERE GoodName = 'sample'))
BEGIN
    SET @ActionResultTag = 2
END

ELSE
BEGIN

    ----- some code

    SET @SubCategoryCode = (
        SELECT SubCategoryCode FROM [dbo].[tb_SubCategory]
        WHERE SubCategoryName = @SubCategoryName AND MainCategoryCode = @MainCategoryCode)

    ----- some code

    SET @GeneralNameCode = (
        SELECT GeneralNameCode FROM [dbo].[tb_GeneralName]
        WHERE GeneralNameTitle = @GeneralNameTitle AND SubCategoryCode = @SubCategoryCode)

    ----- some code

    SET @GoodCode = 'sample'

END

SELECT @ActionResultTag AS ActionResultTag, @GoodCode AS GoodCode
RETURN @ActionResultTag
END
```

and this is my c# code:

```
var ActionResultTag = db.sp_ACars_Insert(MainCode, SubName)
```

Comment: Add parameter to stored procedure and if/else block

Comment: sorry i didn't understand! explain more plz

Comment: As much as code you have shown shouldn't bring back two result sets, don't know where the other result sets are coming from, also use an OUTPUT parameter instead of using `RETURN @ActionResultTag` , return was intended only to show success of failure status of the sps.

Comment: @M.Ali the c# code snippet returns a string -NVARCHAR(4)- parameter (as @SubCategoryCode). but i want to give [ActionResultTag, GoodCode] array from sp.   however i'll try the OUTPUT solution. tnx

Comment: You might also take a look at this article when naming your procedures. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: @SeanLange your refrence is very helpful. i'll change the names of SPs. thank you